# Specifying build dependency in parallel builds using make

Tags: build-process, makefile, build-automation, gnu-make

This is what I have:

1. Test scripts under a folder that use some executables in the source tree.
2. Sources for the executables used above under a separate folder in the source tree.

What I want to achieve:

Do a build, make sure # 2 is done first and only then #1 is done. How do I specify this dependency ? The build is a parallel build and builds other sources under other directories too.

Why : Because during install I want to bundle the executables from # 2 along with the test scripts in #1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just make the appropriate executables dependencies of the test scripts. Is there more to it than that?